# Get Schema Size using JPA Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are using multi-tenant application. Each tenant will have its own schema. Now we need to determine the schema size(Memory Size). Is there a way provided by Spring JPA for this..? How to use Custom JPA Repository for getting the schema size(Memory Size) instead of writing our own implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by 'schema size'?

Comment: what do you mean by Schema size? Number of tables? Memory used?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data JPA can't help you with that.
And as far as I know, neither can any JPA implementation.
The reason is that all of these tools lack necessary information:

- How do you store information in the database. Databases offer lots of storage option, like leaving empty space in blocks to allow for updates that grow rows or compressing data in order to trade storage space for the cost of (de)compressing and many more.
- How much data you put in your tables and how it looks like. For example, you probably have many attributes of type `String` in your model. But how long are they on average? 2 characters? Or 2000?

So for this kind of information you should look more into database tools that might offer this kind of functionality.